# Basic MUI component not working in a Typescript project

Tags: material-ui, shopify-hydrogen

I'm starting a new Hydrogen project ( Shopify React ). I wanted to use the Material UI lib for my project.

Here is my "basic" code :

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';

const Item = styled(Paper)(({ theme }) => ({
  backgroundColor: theme.palette.mode === 'dark' ? '#1A2027' : '#fff',
  ...theme.typography.body2,
  padding: theme.spacing(1),
  textAlign: 'center',
  color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
}));

export default function Home() {
  return (
  <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
      <Grid container spacing={2}>
        <Grid item xs={8}>
          <Item>xs=8</Item>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={4}>
          <Item>xs=4</Item>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={4}>
          <Item>xs=4</Item>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={8}>
          <Item>xs=8</Item>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Box>

  )
}
```

And the error I'm getting :

```
Warning: Only plain objects can be passed to client components from server components. Classes or other objects with methods are not supported. Remove sheet from these props: {key: "css", sheet: {\_insertTag: function, isSpeedy: false, tags: \[...\], ctr: 0, nonce: undefined, key: "css", container: undefined, ...}, nonce: undefined, inserted: {...}, registered: {...}, insert: function}
Error processing route: http://localhost:3000/rx
Error: Functions cannot be passed directly to client components because they're not serializable. Remove \_insertTag (function) from this object, or avoid the entire object: {\_insertTag: function, isSpeedy: false, tags: \[...\], ctr: 0, nonce: undefined, key: "css", container: undefined, ...}
at resolveModelToJSON (/node_modules/@shopify/hydrogen/vendor/react-server-dom-vite/esm/react-server-dom-vite-writer.browser.server.js?v=fa4e9613:1515:13)
at StyleSheet.toJSON (/node_modules/@shopify/hydrogen/vendor/react-server-dom-vite/esm/react-server-dom-vite-writer.browser.server.js?v=fa4e9613:1029:14)
at stringify (\<anonymous\>)
at processModelChunk (/node_modules/@shopify/hydrogen/vendor/react-server-dom-vite/esm/react-server-dom-vite-writer.browser.server.js?v=fa4e9613:164:14)
at retryTask (/node_modules/@shopify/hydrogen/vendor/react-server-dom-vite/esm/react-server-dom-vite-writer.browser.server.js?v=fa4e9613:1625:26)
at performWork (/node_modules/@shopify/hydrogen/vendor/react-server-dom-vite/esm/react-server-dom-vite-writer.browser.server.js?v=fa4e9613:1658:7)
at eval (/node_modules/@shopify/hydrogen/vendor/react-server-dom-vite/esm/react-server-dom-vite-writer.browser.server.js?v=fa4e9613:1755:12)
at scheduleWork (/node_modules/@shopify/hydrogen/vendor/react-server-dom-vite/esm/react-server-dom-vite-writer.browser.server.js?v=fa4e9613:58:3)
at startWork (/node_modules/@shopify/hydrogen/vendor/react-server-dom-vite/esm/react-server-dom-vite-writer.browser.server.js?v=fa4e9613:1754:3)
at Object.start (/node_modules/@shopify/hydrogen/vendor/react-server-dom-vite/esm/react-server-dom-vite-writer.browser.server.js?v=fa4e9613:1866:7)
at setupReadableByteStreamController (node:internal/webstreams/readablestream:3110:23)
at setupReadableByteStreamControllerFromSource (node:internal/webstreams/readablestream:3147:3)
at new ReadableStream (node:internal/webstreams/readablestream:250:7)
at Module.renderToReadableStream (/node_modules/@shopify/hydrogen/vendor/react-server-dom-vite/esm/react-server-dom-vite-writer.browser.server.js?v=fa4e9613:1863:16)
at runRSC (/node_modules/@shopify/hydrogen/dist/esnext/entry-server.js?v=fa4e9613:598:46)
at processRequest (/node_modules/@shopify/hydrogen/dist/esnext/entry-server.js?v=fa4e9613:200:15)
at handleRequest (/node_modules/@shopify/hydrogen/dist/esnext/entry-server.js?v=fa4e9613:163:26)
/.../node_modules/yoga-layout-prebuilt/yoga-layout/build/Release/nbind.js:53
throw ex;
^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'null')
at getOrCreateServerContext (/node_modules/@shopify/hydrogen/vendor/react-server-dom-vite/esm/react-server-dom-vite.js?v=fa4e9613:116:23)
at resolveProvider (/node_modules/@shopify/hydrogen/vendor/react-server-dom-vite/esm/react-server-dom-vite.js?v=fa4e9613:395:51)
at processFullRow (/node_modules/@shopify/hydrogen/vendor/react-server-dom-vite/esm/react-server-dom-vite.js?v=fa4e9613:469:9)
at processBinaryChunk (/node_modules/@shopify/hydrogen/vendor/react-server-dom-vite/esm/react-server-dom-vite.js?v=fa4e9613:513:5)
at progress (/node_modules/@shopify/hydrogen/vendor/react-server-dom-vite/esm/react-server-dom-vite.js?v=fa4e9613:566:5)
```

The problem seems to be related to the lib, when I use basic  balise, I'm not facing any issues.

Thanks !